# Which type of RF harvested device is used now?

Tags: rf, battery-charging, energy-harvesting

I want to do some research about energy harvesting optimization, and I want to ask which type of RF energy harvested device is used now?

first,one transmitter will transmit one signal to the energy harvester

I have A type and B type.

If the RF energy harvester device has five antennas,then type A just feeds the received signal to the RF-DC converter directly, then sums the DC power and charges the battery.

Type B is different from type A. Type B will use some method to let all the phase of received signals be the same, then sum them to be one signal wave, then feed this signal to the RF-DC converter, then charge the battery.

Because I am not the researcher in the electrical, but communication engineering, so I don't really know which RF energy harvest device is used in the real world. Hoping someone can tell me about this information.

[image]
            fig(1) typeA

[image]
 fig(2) typeB

In my thinking,if i have 5 antenna,i need five RF-DC converter in type A ,however, i need one combining and just one RF-DC converter in type B.So should the power consumption of one combining be larger than the sum power consumption of RF-DC converter?

Or the size of that combining is very large,larger than the size of four RF-DC converter,because i search the internet,and find the RF-DC converter :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k807J2JRp_M is very "tiny"

Answer (score 3):

RF signals will pretty much **never** be naturally in phase.  Forcing them to be in phase would require some kind of phase detection and adjustable delay that works in your radio frequency band.  That's going to be complicated, and difficult to do at high frequencies.

It would be much easier to convert the received RF to DC, then connect the DC sources in parallel (or in series for that matter.)

I see you asked a related question on the [DSP stack exchange.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62110/why-does-almost-all-paper-usually-add-the-rf-wave-power-directlyit-seems-like-f)

The most likely reason that those papers just sum the RF is that the received signals are presumed to be completely unrelated to each other so that simply connecting them in parallel would add them all to a sort of "average power."

---

Have you had a look at how much energy you could reasonably expect to collect?  I ran through some numbers in [this answer to a similar question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/455432/47070)

In that answer, I assumed simple dipole antennas with no gain, 5 watts transmit power, 2.4GHz as the transmit frequency, and 1 meter as the distance.  I then used [this calculator](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/friis-transmission-calculator) to estimate the received power.

Given those unrealistically good conditions, the received power was just 0.00049455W.  That's not quite 500 microwatts.

What ever device you are powering will have to operate at very low power, or collect energy for a long time so that it can do a short task at high power once in a (long) while.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101406/discussion-on-answer-by-jre-which-type-of-rf-harvested-device-is-used-now). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).